# why is `ctrl -h` not work in insert mode?(version gvim 8.1.1)

Tags: vim

In "Practical Vim" (second edition), the writer says `<c-h>` can delete back a character. I've tried in git bash, and it worked. However, it doesn't work in gvim in win10 as expected.

When I enter something in insert mode, I can use `<c-h>`, `<c-w>` and `<c-u>` before I leave insert mode. When I switch to insert mode without entering anything, `<c-h>`, `<c-w>` and `<c-u>` don't work.

Note that `<c-h>` is not mapped (`:map <c-h>` prints `No mapping found`).

Comment: Works in gvim of Linux. maybe problem of Windows.

Comment: Yes, I ran gvim in win10.

Comment: Might be a Windows quirk or you mapped it to something. What's the output of `:map <c-h>`? If this returns "No mapping found", update you question, that `<c-h>` is not mapped.

Comment: Check your 'backspace' setting

Comment: @Ralf thank you. The output of  ```:map <c-h>``` is ```No mapping found```.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt thanks for your helping, but how to check my ```backspace``` setting? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: New founding. when I input sth in insert mode, I can use <c-h>, <c-w>, <c-u> before I leave insert mode. And when I switch to insert mode without input anything, <c-h>, <c-w>, <c-u> don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim, by default, does only allow to delete characters that you typed since you entered insert mode. It does not allow to delete chars before the point where you started inserting. This behavior is inherited from the original Vi.

To change that, Vim has the option `'backspace'`. It configures how `<Backspace>`, `<Del>`, `<c-w>` and `<c-u>` work. Add the following to your `_vimrc` and Vim will behave as you expect:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Then you can backspace over autoindent, start of insert and end-of-lines.

See `:help 'backspace'`.

Comment: Actually, if backspace does not behave as expected and the backspace option is empty, it's a good indication, the Vim is running in compatible mode

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt But I started vim by ```vim -u NONE -N```.

Comment: @Aliar If you have started Vim in non-compatible mode, than the backspace option should not have been empty. Check the output of `:verbose :set bs? ` to find out why it is still empty

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I think that `backspace` is not affected by compatible or not. It is only set, if the user has no `.vimrc` (or `.vim/vimrc`), because in that case `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` is sourced. If you have a `vimrc`, you have to set `backspace` yourself (or explicitly load `defaults.vim` as described in `:help defaults.vim`) .

Comment: @RAlf no that is not true. As mentioned in the help at `:h 'backspace'` it will be set to empty for compatible mode. Try it out, do `:set cp` and check your backspace setting.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I understand, that `bs` is set to empty, when switching to compatible mode, but don't see in the docs, that is is set to anything other in nocompatible. The docs only mention `defaults.vim`. If I start `vim -u NONE -N`, and do a `:verbose set bs?`, I just get `backspace=`. (Vim 8.1.847 on Linux)

Comment: Check the help at `:h 'compatible'`, it mentions every option that is affected by setting the compatible mode. I thought, when starting `vim -u NONE -N` that not only compatible will be turned off, but all affected options as well. Apparently, I remember wrong (or this behaviour changed from the past).